# Simple chat application not working on live website

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, port

I'am completely new to NodeJs. I was following a tutorial online on how to make a socket.io(chat application). I made a simple application that works offline, but in order for it to work, I have to go to the command prompt, go into my project and type : **node server** : to start up a sever on port 3000.

I wanted to put this small application onto my website, which I did [here](http://davidtrushkov.com/iochat/)

But when I try to type something in the chat box it wont display, and its giving me a bunch of errors in the console. I know it probably has something to do with the port. I just don't know how would I make it work on a live website.

Here is my server side code:

```
// Include all of our modules
var express = require('express');

// Set variable "app" = to the 'express' variable
var app = express();

// Set our server variable, and pass in 'app' variable
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

// Include socket.io and listen to the 'server' variable
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


// * We are going to have 2 arrays
// One for users, other one for connections
users = [];
connections = [];


// Run the server, and listen to assigned port
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);


console.log('Server running...');


// Create a route, a function is going to take in a "request" and a "response"
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


// Open a connection with socket.io
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

    // Write our disconnect, and console.log how many are still connected
    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
    });


    // Send message
    socket.on('send message', function (data) {
        // emmit a new message event
        io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data});
    })

});
```

Here is my client side code:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Online Users</h4>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="users"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>

                <form id="messageForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter a message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message">
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
            var $message = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            // create a event when form is submitted
            $messageForm.submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
                $message.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data) {
                $chat.append('<div class="well">'+data.msg+'</div>');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: go to this website: http://davidtrushkov.com/iochat/   and inspect console

Answer (score 0):

socket.io  auto-configures its connection when we ommit a connection url

To be precise I always pass the url to io.connect  [(more info)](http://socket.io/docs/)

```
var socket = io.connect('http://<website_name>:<port>/');
```

like for example in your case:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://davidtrushkov.com:3000/');
```

Comment: Wouldn't be **http://davidtrushkov.com/iochat/** because I put this website in the **iochat** directory?

Comment: I tried this: **var socket = io.connect('http://davidtrushkov.com:3000/');**, but still dosent work. Getting errors **socket.io.js:1456 GET http://davidtrushkov.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LKHt9hK net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**

Comment: is davidtrushkov.com rendered by some other server (other than nodeJs express) ? if yes then you may have give the full path 
" davidtrushkov.com/iochat"

Comment: I see you are now using <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> in your client side. This will also not work you , you need to give full absolute path to the socket.io.js file like
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js"></script> as your parent URL is not where your node express is working

Comment: When you said **is davidtrushkov.com rendered by some other server (other than nodeJs express) ?**, how would I go check that. davidtrushkov.com is hosted by siteground.com

Comment: I mean is the rest of the website on "davidtrushkov.com" is written in PHP and served by apache server ? as I saw one PHPSESSION cookie being saved at some time.

Comment: Yes it is written in PHP and  I'm pretty sure it is served by Apache

Comment: may be your proxy server doesn't support websockets. Have you checked their docs?